# It is possible to use WCF + DTO's + Automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, automapper

I want to use automapper with a structure that uses WCF + DTO's but I want to know how the question of the eager loading with entity framework 4.0 work with the mappings of the automap.

Comment: You don't really state a question here, and then randomly bring up entity framework that seems unrelated, please elaborate more.

Comment: well, I just want to know if there is any issues with eager loading and the automapper auto-mapping feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently use Automapper with LightSpeed ORM (which makes Entity Framework look like a prototypea btw).  It just works.  It wont matter if your entities are eager or lazy loaded or used via WCF or not. Automapper is resolving the referenced entities the same way you would in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

"well, I just want to know if there is any issues with eager loading and the automapper auto-mapping feature. "

No.

In fact so "No." that it makes me wonder why you would think there would be problems.

Eager loading fills properties up with data.
Automapper moves property values around.

What exactly are you trying to do?